# Search results get appended and not updated when the query is rerun

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code, which uses an API to search for movies. When I search for a movie for the first time, the results are displayed, but for my second query, the results get appended to the previous list of results, but they should get updated instead of getting appended. Please let me know the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#results-list').on('click', 'li', function(){

    var imdbID = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + imdbID,
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(movie){
        var movieTitle = movie['Title'];
        var movieYear = movie['Year'];
        var movieRuntime = movie['Runtime'];
        var movieGenre = movie['Genre'];
        var movieDirector = movie['Director'];
        var moviePlot = movie['Plot'];
        var moviePoster = movie['Poster'];
        var selectionBox = $('#selected');
        var selectionBody = $('#selected-result');
        var listElements = $('<li><h3></h3></li>');

        //listElements.append(movieTitle);

        selectionBody.append('<span><h2>' + movieTitle + ' :: ' + movieYear + '</h2></span>');

        selectionBox.append('<span><h5>Runtime: ' + movieRuntime + '</h5></span>');

        selectionBox.append('<span><h5>Director: ' + movieDirector + '</h5></span>');

        selectionBox.append('<span><h5>Plot: ' + moviePlot + '</h5></span>');

        selectionBox.append('<span><img src="' + moviePoster + '""></span>');

      }

    });

  });


  $('form').bind('keyup submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    var searchQuery = $('#input-box').val();

    //var resultsBox = $('#search-results');
    var resultsList = $('#results-list');
    //var selectionBox = $('#selected-result');
    var searchResults;
    //var selectedResult;
    var imdb;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + searchQuery,
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(omdb){
        $('#input-box').html(' ');
        searchResults = omdb.Search;
        for(i=0; i<searchResults.length; i+=1){
          var listLink = $("<a href='#'></a>");
          var title = searchResults[i]['Title'];
          var year = searchResults[i]['Year'];
          imdb = searchResults[i]['imdbID'];
          var listItem = $('<li data-id="' + imdb + '"></li>');

          listLink.append(year, " : ", title);
          listItem.append(listLink);
          resultsList.append(listItem);
          //http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + imdbID + "'></a>
        }
      },
      error: function(){
        $('.error').slideDown();
        setTimeout(function(){$('.error').slideUp();}, 3000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `.empty()` before appending to clear out the old contents of the DIV.

Comment: Question: "Why do the results get appended?" Code: `resultsList.append` - doesn't look suspicious at all?

Answer (score 0):

As the two guys @Barmar and @Zhilhao pointed out, you are constantly appending to your list without clearing it.

```
$('#results-list').empty();
```